# Complex Regex to gsub expression

Tags: regex, ruby, gsub

I am struggling to convert a regex to a successful gsub expression.

I am trying to extract portions of a url so that I can replace with specific size segements.

Eg.

https://example.com//images/1971AW/full/full/0/default.jpg
or
https://example.com//images/1971AW/140,870,1800,1778/full/0/default.jpg

should both be converted to:
https://example.com//images/1971AW/500,/full/0/default.jpg

I've used the regex editor and found that the following expression highlights the portion I wish . to target:
`[^/]*\/[^/]*\/0`

However I am not having any success when trying to convert this to a find and replace expression with gsub.

This is what I have so far:
`resize_image_url = image_url.gsub(/[^/]*\/[^/]*\/0/, "full/500,/0,")`
where image_url is one of the url examples above.

Here is the error output:

> lib/mixin.rb:25: premature end of char-class: /[^/ lib/mixin.rb:25:
>   syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting ')' ...mage_url =
>   image_url.gsub(/[^/]*/[^/]*/0/, "full/500,/0,") ...
>   ^ lib/mixin.rb:25: premature end of char-class: /[^/ lib/mixin.rb:25:
>   syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting keyword_end ...l =
>   image_url.gsub(/[^/]*/[^/]*/0/, "full/500,/0,") ...
>   ^ lib/mixin.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
>   ...age_url.gsub(/[^/]*/[^/]*/0/, "full/500,/0,") ...
>   ^ lib/mixin.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
>   .../]*/[^/]*/0/, "full/500,/0,")

Could somebody assist with the construction of the gsub please?

Comment: Thanks, I've added that and amended my question as I still get errors in gsub section.

Comment: Try escaping the forward slash in the character class `resize_image_url = image_url.gsub(/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/0/, "full/500,/0,")`

Comment: That's it! It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could also use the alternative RegExp syntax: `%r{[^/]*/[^/]*/0}`. You can use any separator you want, in this case `{}`, but `||`, `[]`, `!!`, etc. should all work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
resize_image_url = image_url.gsub(/[^/]*\/[^/]*\/0/, "full/500,/0,")
```

to

```
resize_image_url = image_url.gsub(/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/0/, "full/500,/0,")
```